# Android Version Textview Writer

Tags: android

Is there another method to get version and is it healthy to get version this way?

```
String appName=getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
String versionName=BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
String versionCode=String.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);
Toast.makeText(getContext(),"App Name : "+appName+" version Name : "+versionName+"versionCode : "+versionCode,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This way of doing it is just fine-  it's fully supported and should always work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will continue to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method of mine ->

```
private String getCurrentVersion() {
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo pInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
        return pInfo.versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return "0.0";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is overly complicated-  his version works and is far simpler.  There's no reason to use getPackageInfo, that exists so other apps can find out about your app.

Comment: Is getPackageInfo not safe?

Comment: It's safe, its just overcomplicated.  That data is in your BuildConfig, and can be instantly read from there.  Yours requires a Context (to call getPackageManager) and does a slow service call to an OS provided service.  You have a 7 line function with a hidden service call and an error value, or `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` which just reads a constant and can't error.